# Why are (const char[2]){'A', '\0'} and "A" placed in different memory locations?

Tags: c++

In my investigation, the memory locations of `(const char[2]){'A', '\0'}` and `"A"`
are different.

```
cout<< &(const char[2]){'A', '\0'} <<endl; 
cout<< &"A" <<endl;
```

Why are they placed in different memory locations?

Comment: Did you use `-O3`?

Comment: `(const char[2]){'A', '\0'}` is a temporary object while `"A"` is a string literal, they are different objects.  string literals are also static, which normally has its own section of memory for those objects.

Comment: As @NathanOliver says and also _"...Whether string literals can overlap and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same object is unspecified. That means that identical string literals may or may not compare equal when compared by pointer...."_ [String literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: C or C++? Pick **one**.

Comment: `(const char[2]){'A', '\0'}` is not legal. There are no compound literals in C++.

Comment: As @n.m. says, that's not legal C++. If it compile at all, it's because you're using compiler extensions, which C++ has no say about. For Clang and GCC, use `-pedantic-errors` to stick to legal C++

Comment: Even if `(const char[2]){'A', '\0'}` compiled, it would produce a temporary object, and it is not legal to take the address of a temporary object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(const char[2]){'A', '\0'}` is not legal standard C++.

If it compiles for you, then your compiler is accepting it as an extension to the language and whatever behavior it has would depend on your compiler. This is not standardized. This construct is however allowed in standard C and called a *compound literal* there. It does *not* behave like a string literal in C.

But in any case, even if you wrote

```
cout<< &"A" <<endl;
cout<< &"A" <<endl;
```

there is no guarantee that you will get the same result twice. The compiler is completely free to decide how to choose the memory location for string literals. It could use two different locations or reuse the same for both uses of `"A"`. It may also overlap memory used for different string literals, etc.